# Set strikeout for specific value only in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am sorry before if the title is not too descriptive.

My goal is to create report like this (ignore the red line):
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATTam.png)

In the `Height (m)` field, I create formula in the Formula Fields to check two values of height.

```
If IsNull({stored.RevisedHeight}) or {stored.RevisedHeight} = "" then
    {stored.Height} 
Else
    {stored.Height} + ChrW(13) + {stored.RevisedHeight}
```

I need to set strikeout style for value `{stored.Height}` only in the Else condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
If IsNull({stored.RevisedHeight}) or {stored.RevisedHeight} = "" then
    {stored.Height} 
Else
    "<Strike>" + {stored.Height} + "</Strike>" + ChrW(13) + {stored.RevisedHeight}
```

Right-click the formula object on the report canvas, 
**Format Field...**  select **Paragraph** tab, set *Text Interpretation* option to 'HTML Text'.

Comment: Hi @MilletSoftware, is it possible to do this on Format Object Formula only? I mean without Formula Fields.

Comment: You could place the two objects one above the other (freely, or inside a text object) and use the conditional Strikeout format expression only for the {stored.Height}.

Comment: The advantage of placing them in a text object is that you can turn on the text object format option of 'Suppress Embedded Field Blank Lines'

Comment: I see, that should do the trick, thanks a lot @MilletSoftware